# Is it possible to get a generic that's contstrained to one of a string literal union in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function that returns a model given it's `type`, as demonstrated [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.5.1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDSBLAdgEwM5wC8cARAGYQQlwA+pARgIZTV0lMBeJA3AFC-YYwKGUYBjVAFkIOYABsCAb15xVcChABccAGKVpsuXzVwmUbQCFmB+cbWdLjDjaO8AvvzFzGeAnogucMomGtp4MFDYAOZEcADkGnHunt6+cFZQgcH2zGER0bFxZnF8HrxePgRWzjLyQSo5HHmRWDHERU4lybxkAK5YYjAYEFhwUcAwLgA8ACpwoEK4BJhLAHwAFEgo2jMAlNoueADaMwC69SZ4AO4YMGIAFnCbyMC7FyZqYj6oCZRx2tkPh8oBNelBRlhgFddPpanJ1rsGkCPEDVF88D9igCkajVCCYGCIVD0tY4QicSYUaj0ZjOtjcSZ8YS4JDodUXOTcVTVGUTJVhDAAHLAABuwmeKF2pX4fQGQxGcH5sGFYqg6xA2khqv2LNFwneqhg9ygEGhrLgAFEoCa1QADACqkPAwEGwBwcBFjDkvVQABJFCA3Lapd0xCNwupYYZYuNJmTfhA4oiw1gI1d7ox4MRYxy4lgIDAALSJXZAA).

I have two issues currently, which are probably related:

1. without casting each return (lines 24, 27, 30) using `as Models[T]` I can't get it to compile.
2. I can't get `assertNever` to work here, even though the code works fine from the user's view (see lines 41-42).

Is it possible to make this work somehow in TypeScript currently? This is happenning since v3.5, but also happens in v3.6 and v3.7.

Comment: No, this is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995); generic type parameters do not get narrowed via control flow analysis.  Use assertions and move on, *or*, use true indexing like in `return { get foo() { return new FooModel() }, get bar() { return new BarModel() }, get baz() { return new BazModel() } }[type]`

Comment: An alternative which is essentially the same as a type assertion but might be stylistically preferable. This also still provides enough type safety to address your `assertNever` issue by using a default block. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQLJwCaoDYA8AKoqgB5SpjYDOiA0jNTQHwAUUAngA6oBciIgEoBWXHhoBtIgF0A3AChQkWAhTox+Dj34MmtEYk0TJjZjMQBvBYluIaAdxhQIAC0TbeQqzbt+IAIY0qIgA5MBwcKEC1n5xdgBO6CAJSGCoDogAYpHGbEK+8QC+hXGBwWEARgEJ0T7x8UlQKWkZiABCNXkFDYglveUhodUAXnWxvYnJqYjpmZ0j3aV+-Q24wAEgeFB8yw1BwQlQAHKoAG6oCZ6oQoorCiVAA

Comment: Thank you both - I didn't find that issue initially in my GitHub search. Also, I went with @KSab's solution - which works great. While it's a bit more verbose in the declaration, I prefer it in this specific case. Thank you both.